# Smartphone app accessible before authentication screen

Tags: android, iphone

Is it possible to create an app on iphone and android that is accessible before the authentication screen, just like the "emergency dialler".

I searched on google but I cant seem to find relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android perhaps, depends on what you want exactly.  You can make an app that appears above the keyguard by specifying FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED.  You can make it turn on the display with a wakelock or the flag  FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON.  You can make it dismiss the keyguard with FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD .  But some of these will only work with a non-secure keyguard (one that doesn't require a password).

Comment: I need more of an app that can be read outside of the "keyguard".